# Modify SVN Repository structure while having checked out working copy

Tags: svn, version-control, svn-repository

I need to reorganize my company's repository.

Currently I have a structure that looks like this:

```
\Project1
     \trunk
     \branches
     \tags
\Project2
     \trunk
     \branches
     \tags
.
.
.
```

Since we understood that both projects are dependent one on the other, we decided to merge the projects to the following structure:

```
\trunk
    \Project1
    \Project2
    .
    .
    .
\branches
\tags
```

The actual repository is far more complex. We have a lot more projects that need to be merged to a single \trunk,branches,tags structure. That means that it is going to take a while to make the modification.

Is it possible to make the modification while allowing the users continue committing to the repository?

I though about the following method:

1. Dump the whole repository (old_repo)
2. Load it to a new repository (new_repo)
3. Reorganize new_repo while allowing the users continue using old_repo.
4. Dump the additional commits from the old_repositories that were made during the modification.
5. Load the last dump to new_repo.

Will it work?

I think that due to the structural change, the last load will fail.

Comment: The last load will not fail, but it will add folders as per the old repository. So this method is not useful. Better lock the repository for sometime and use tools like tortoise-svn (repo-browser) in which you can drag and drop the folders to change the directory structures easily.

Comment: You are correct. I built a test repository with a similar structure, and tried this scenario. The old repository folder structure was added.

Comment: Assuming that I lock the repository for changes for the duration of the reorganization, what happens to the checked out working copies? Is it safe to assume the the 'Switch' operation from TortoiseSVN works correctly?

Comment: Switch should work. For a safer side you can give some time to the developers for committing their existing modifications, so that in case switch is not working they can do fresh checkout.

Comment: I'v decided to go along with your suggestion to lock the repository for the duration of the reorganization.